# Convert this float to a correct decimal

Tags: powershell

I have hard time trying convert this from a JSON Property to an regular decimal :

[DBG]: PS C:\scripts>> $token.balance
8,8458571112536E+20

I want it as 884.58571112536 and not 8,8458571112536E+20

How I can convert like this in powershell ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

`8,8458571112536E+20` is not equivalent to `884.58571112536` , it is `884585711125360000000`.

When you convert `8,8458571112536E+20` from json, it will be converted as string. To change it to a number, you can replace `,` with `.` and then convert it to decimal like following:

```
$json = "{'balance' : '8,8458571112536E+20' }"
$token = ConvertFrom-Json -InputObject $json
$token.balance = [Decimal]([Double]::Parse($token.balance.Replace(',','.')))
$token.balance
```

Which shows `884585711125360000000` in output.

Comment: Thank you for your help, could you explain me why I browse the Website the value is 884.58571112536 and not 884585711125360000000 grabbed from an API. Again thanks

Comment: To be honest I don't have any idea about the context around the question and I just tried to answer your question. Maybe the unit that you see in the website is different from what you received from API. Like for example seeing something in milligram and megaton. (just an example)

Comment: I have this note on the API about this field :  balance:   # token balance (as is, not reduced to a floating point value). What could be mean ? Again thanks , it's help me https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/wiki/Ethplorer-API?from=etop

Comment: Maybe it's better to ask from authors of the API. You can take a look at [Issue page](https://github.com/EverexIO/Ethplorer/issues) and if you think it's an issue, register a new one.

Comment: Ok I got my reply there is a sample of my JSON there is a decimal value (here 18).